# Does a diffeomorphism map a compact surface to another compact surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, compactness

Suppose $S$ is a $C^k$ compact hypersurface (in the sense that I can do things like $\sup_{x \in S}f(s) < K$ for continuous function $f$). If we have a $C^l$ diffeomorphism $F$, is $F(S)$ also a compact hypersurface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being compact is a property of topological spaces: Some spaces are compact, others aren't. When $f:\ X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism between two spaces $X$ and $Y$ then both spaces are compact, or both are non-compact. When $f$ is a diffeomorphism between two manifolds $X$ and $Y$ then a fortiori $f$ is a homeomorphism. Therefore, when $X$ is compact, $Y$ has to be compact as well.